# Create Http request with POST

Tags: http, azure, arduino, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

```cpp
void send_request(){
    //client.println("POST /tables/arduino_table HTTP/1.1");
    //client.println("Host: tremortest1.azurewebsites.net");
    //client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
    char value[]="IRTHE"; 
    Serial.print("sending ");
    Serial.println(value);

    // POST URI
    sprintf(buffer, "POST /tables/%s HTTP/1.1", table_name);
    client.println(buffer);

    // Host header
    sprintf(buffer, "Host: %s", server);
    client.println(buffer);

    // Azure Mobile Services application key
    //sprintf(buffer, "ZUMO-API-VERSION: %s", ver);
    //client.println(buffer);

    // JSON content type
    client.println("Content-Type: application/json");

    // POST body
    sprintf(buffer, "{\"value\": %d}", value);

    // Content length
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(strlen(buffer));
}
```

I am trying to add a value to an existing table in Azure via this code:

[image: azure swagger screenshot]

Can anybody help me write the POST request for Arduino?

Comment: its should give you a curl request for free?

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a code-writing service - you should consider editing your question to show where you're stuck.

Comment: this is the only documentation azure gave me... i want to make the POST request via arduino. To be more specific i want to add a char[] value to a table that exists in a mobile app on azure.

Comment: i edited the question as you reccomended @DavidMakogon

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article on how to do a HTTP POST for Arduino: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=155218.0